# IvoryCKEditorBundle : Display Toolbar Items with Role

Tags: symfony, ckeditor

I want displaying of Toolbar items of the WYSIWYG to be per Role, for example if the user has the ROLE_ADMIN, he sees all items.

Please suggest how can I do that. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{% if is_granted('ROLE_*ROLE*' %}` in your twig template or the security contexts' `isGranted('ROLE_*ROLE*')` if you are using something like KnpMenuBundle.